# JavaScript Array Formatting problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can someone assist me with formatting this JavaScript array correctly?  I am obviously missing something fundamental:

### Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var widths = new Array("225","320","480", "--");
    var sidewalls = new Array();
    sidewalls["225"] = new Array("65","55","45","40", "--");
        var rims["225"] = new Array();
            rims["225"]["65"] = new Array("R17", "--");
            rims["225"]["55"] = new Array("R17","R18", "--");
            rims["225"]["45"] = new Array("R17", "--");
            rims["225"]["40"] = new Array("R18", "--");
    sidewalls["320"] = new Array("70", "--");
        var rims["320"] = new Array();
            rims["320"]["70"] = new Array("R20","R24", "--");
    sidewalls["480"] = new Array("65", "--");
        var rims["480"] = new Array();
            rims["480"]["65"] = new Array("R28", "--");

</script>
```

### PHP used to generate the above JavaScript:

```
<?php   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    list($width, $sidewall, $rim) = explode("/",$row['meta_value']); $menu[$width][$sidewall][$rim] = 1; } 

    $widths = implode('","', array_keys($menu));
        print "var widths = new Array(\"$widths\", \"--\");\n";
        print "\nvar sidewalls = new Array();\n";

    foreach($menu as $width => $sidewall_array) {
        $sidewalls = implode('","', array_keys($sidewall_array));
            print "sidewalls[\"$width\"] = new Array(\"$sidewalls\", \"--\");";
            print "\nvar rims[\"$width\"] = new Array();\n";

    foreach($sidewall_array as $sidewall => $rim_array) {
        $rims = implode('","', array_keys($rim_array));
            print "rims[\"$width\"][\"$sidewall\"] = new Array(\"$rims\", \"--\");";

    }
} ?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Stu

Comment: It is populating <select> menus, three of them, each relational. (widths, sidewalls and rims)

Comment: Consider `[a, b, c]` instead of `new Array(a, b, c)`

Comment: I am whizzing around in circles with options and unable to complete an answer, I will pay for this code, i need three relational menus.. stuart[dot]stalker[at]gmail[dot]com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be putting `var` in front of array assignments, just the initial definitions.

So `var widths = ...` is fine, but `var rims["225"] = ...` is incorrect and should just be `rims["225"] = ...`.

Change your php; in the line of code that outputs that text remove the "var". Change this:

```
print "\nvar rims[\"$width\"] = new Array();\n";
```

To this:

```
print "\nrims[\"$width\"] = new Array();\n";
```

That will solve your problem. But really, this overall solution is not the best. You ought to consider looking into the [`json-encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) php method.

You can take a fully-structured php data structure and with this one command convert to something that can be read by javascript. Try replacing your php with the below and see what happens (note that this is untested, but this is the basic idea):

```
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { list($width, $sidewall, $rim) = explode("/",$row['meta_value']); $menu[$width][$sidewall][$rim] = 1; }

    print "var widths = " . json_encode(array_keys($menu)) . ";\n";
    print "var sidewalls = " . json_encode($menu) . ";\n";
?>
```

Comment: Fancy earning some beer tokens for the rewrite, including the menus? I want to cry!! stuart.stalker[at]gmail[dot]com

Comment: +1 for the `json_encode` @Stuart: Look into [JSON (Javascript Object Notation)](http://www.json.org/)